# How to take a few values in column of a CSV file and export it to an python array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have an CSV file something like:

```
Total Energy                 Pump        Diswasher      Freezer
2015-04-15T13:00:00+0200     70          50             80
2015-04-15T14:00:00+0400     80          40             80
2015-04-15T15:00:00+0300     30          90             80
2015-04-15T16:00:00+0600     40          80             80
2015-04-15T17:00:00+0700     50          70             80
```

I want to take only the first 3 values of each column and export to different Python arrays. But for the total energy, I want to take only the value after "+" sign only.

```
The result is expected something like:
Total_energy = [200, 400, 300]
Pump = [70, 80, 30]
Diswasher = [50, 40, 90]
Freezer = [80, 80, 80]
```

I have two issue:
1. Only take the first three values in each column and I do not want to take the whole column.
2. First column(Total Energy) I only need the value after "+" sign

```
import pandas
colnames = ['Total_energy', 'Pump', 'Diswasher',]
data = pandas.read_csv('Data_60min.csv', names=colnames)
names = data.name.tolist()
Total_energy = data.Total_energy.tolist()
Pump = data.Pump.tolist()
Diswasher = data.Diswasher.tolist()
```

I can do something like above but it takes for the whole column and also I do not know how to take the value after the "+" sign only.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5yru.png)

Answer (score 1):

First filter top 3 rows by [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) or [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
data = data.head(3)
```

Or:

```
data = data.iloc[:3]
```

then seelct values after `+` by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) or by [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
data['Total_energy'] = data['Total_energy'].str.split('+').str[1].astype(int)

data['Total_energy'] = data['Total_energy'].str.extract('\+(.+)', expand=False).astype(int)
```

Last is possible create dictionary and select by keys for lists:

```
d = data.to_dict('list')
print (d)
{'Total_energy': [200, 400, 300], 
 'Pump': [70, 80, 30], 
 'Diswasher': [50, 40, 90], 
  'Freezer': [80, 80, 80]}

print (d['Total_energy'])
[200, 400, 300]

print (d['Pump'])
[70, 80, 30]
```

Also working select each column separately like in your solution:

```
names = data.name.tolist()
Total_energy = data.Total_energy.tolist()
Pump = data.Pump.tolist()
Diswasher = data.Diswasher.tolist()
```

EDIT:

If need filter columns in read_csv by names is use parameter `usecols`, not `names`:

```
colnames = ['cet_cest_timestamp', 'DE_KN_residential2_circulation_pump', 'DE_KN_residential2_dishwasher'] 
data = pd.read_csv('household_data_60min_singleindex.csv', usecols=colnames) 
print (data.head())

         cet_cest_timestamp  DE_KN_residential2_circulation_pump  \
0  2015-04-15T13:00:00+0200                               19.776   
1  2015-04-15T14:00:00+0200                               19.780   
2  2015-04-15T15:00:00+0200                               19.784   
3  2015-04-15T16:00:00+0200                               19.788   
4  2015-04-15T17:00:00+0200                               19.854   

   DE_KN_residential2_dishwasher  
0                          2.765  
1                          2.765  
2                          2.765  
3                          2.765  
4                          2.765
```

Comment: Thanks but my output is just something like: [nan, nan, nan] instead of float number. It is the problem with data type or somethings.

Comment: @Thinsheep -  What is `print (data.info())` ?

Comment: Data columns (total 4 columns):
DE_KN_industrial1_total_energy        0 non-null float64
DE_KN_residential2_circulation_pump    0 non-null object
DE_KN_residential2_dishwasher          0 non-null object
DE_KN_residential2_freezer             0 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(3)

nan mean null (nothing in the box i guess)

Comment: @Thinsheep - hmmm, hard question, how working change `data['Total_energy'] = data['Total_energy'].str.split('+').str[1].astype(int)` to `data['Total_energy'] = data['Total_energy'].astype(str).str.split('+').str[1].astype(int)` ?

Comment: I guess your code is fine. only somehow it said the content of my column is empty. 
Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: @Thinsheep - So only remove `.astype(int)` like `data['Total_energy'] = data['Total_energy'].str.split('+').str[1]`

Comment: This is where I get my .csv file. I take the one in "60 minute" if you follow the row a little bit further you will see the value of some columns.
https://data.open-power-system-data.org/household_data/2017-11-10

Comment: @Thinsheep - yes, data are downloaded and checked. but not sure if understand what need - do you need first non missing values per specified columns, right?

Comment: print(Total_Energy)
print(Pump)
print(Dishwasher)

I collect the data for residential2 but the results is residential6, that why it is shown as nan, nan, nan

Somehow, the print results jump to other columns.
[nan, nan]

['DE_KN_residential6_pv', nan]

['DE_KN_residential6_washing_machine', nan]

sorry for very bad looking writing

Comment: here is the code
colnames = ['cet_cest_timestamp', 'DE_KN_residential2_circulation_pump', 'DE_KN_residential2_dishwasher', 
data = pandas.read_csv('household_data_60min_singleindex.csv', names=colnames)
data = data.iloc[:2]
data['cet_cest_timestamp'] = data['cet_cest_timestamp'].str.split('+').str[1].astype(float)
Total_Energy = data.cet_cest_timestamp.tolist()
Pump = data.DE_KN_residential2_circulation_pump.tolist()
Dishwasher = data.DE_KN_residential2_dishwasher.tolist()
Freezer = data.DE_KN_residential2_freezer.tolist()

Comment: @Thinsheep - There is problem in parameter, need `usecols` like `data = pd.read_csv('household_data_60min_singleindex.csv', usecols=colnames) `

Comment: That is perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result you want by using:

```
Total_energy = data.loc[:2, "Total Energy"].apply(lambda x: int(x.split("+")[1])).tolist()
Pump = data.loc[:2, "Pump"].tolist()
Diswasher = data.loc[:2, "Diswasher"].tolist()
```

Use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to select the rows and column you want and [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to get the value after the "+" sign for Total Energy.

Comment: Thank you but it reports:
'Key length (1) was greater than MultiIndex lexsort depth (0)'. Do you have experience with this.

Comment: All the columns shown in your sample data are regular columns or are some of them part of the index for the dataframe?

Comment: This is where I get my .csv file. I take the one in "60 minute" if you follow the row a little bit further you will see the value of some columns.
https://data.open-power-system-data.org/household_data/2017-11-10